# Accessing UIScrolView form other controller

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a UIScrollView which is added modally form a segue in UIStoryboard. I would like to access a UIScrollView in UIViewController ViewController from controller B, I tried this code:

```
ViewController *linkToA;
linkToA = [[ViewController alloc] init];
linkToA = (ViewController*)self.presentingViewController;
linkToA.groupPass.text = @"cool party ajdaj";
[linkToA.scroll1.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

The code doesn't give errors, but doesn't do anything.

I import the controller in this way:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
```

and in the ViewController.h I have:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroll1;
```

What is the problem??

Answer (score -1):

linkToA IBOutlets will be not accesible while linkToA view controller will not be pushed to nav controller or presented modally

Comment: try output linkToA to console before do something